# How to make the regexp ignore a new line in python?

Tags: python, regex

I use the regex like that

```
return(\s+([^"\n;]+))?;
```

in order to match the return statement in obj-c,but when I use it through python like this:

```
re.sub(r'return(\s+([^"\n;]+))?;',r'{\g<0>}',str(content))
```

I find that it match like this statement

```
//please {return
[self funcA];}
```

and make the code error.How can I deal with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that your regex has `\s` that matches any whitespace.

You might want to just match literal spaces or tabs with `[ \t]`:

```
r'return([ \t]+([^"\n;]+))?;'
```

([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM6mK2/2)) or - better:

```
r'return[ \t]+[^"\n;]*;'
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM6mK2/3)

Comment: thank you very much，and I have anthor question that how can I match these situation =======>>> return @"hello world";       and    "return this question ";   , when I change the regex like this  r'return[ \t]+[^\n;]*;'   It will make << "return this question "; >> error like this  "{return this question "; }

Comment: Sorry, could you share a demo link like https://regex101.com/r/mM6mK2/3?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/mM6mK2/4   and  https://regex101.com/r/mM6mK2/5    thank you

Comment: See [demo 6](https://regex101.com/r/mM6mK2/6) and [demo 7](https://regex101.com/r/mM6mK2/7).